# reading n-th row in oledbdatareader in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, oledbdatareader

I have a excel sheet showing employees salary details in department wise.
Just I need to save these details in to MySql .

When I use oledbdatareader,it reads from the first row. But I have to choose from different rows. Below im showing sample excel sheet

```
Dept    Software         
Name    Gross   Deductions  NetPay
AAA    10000    2000        8000
BBB    10000    1000        9000
Dept    HR       
Name    Gross   Deductions  NetPay
CCC    20000        1000     19000
```

Here each line is a row. I have to take third row ,fourth row and then last row (in this example).

```
AAA    10000    2000        8000
BBB    10000    1000        9000
CCC    20000    1000       19000
```

How can i achieve this?
I tried like this.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {           

   string path = "C:\\Payslip.xls";
   string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet3$]";
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '" + path + "'" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
   conn.Open();              

try
{
        OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();             

        while (odr.Read())
        {                               
                name = odr[0].ToString();            
                gross = odr[1].ToString();     
                ded = odr[2].ToString();                
                net = odr[3].ToString();        

                connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                String sQuery = "insert into salary (EmployeeName, Gross) values(@a, @b)";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sQuery, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", gross); 

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                connection.Close();
            }    
      }    
      catch (Exception ex)    
      {
          Label1.Text = ex.Message;                        
      }                 
}
```

Comment: No built in support from `DataReader` to read a specific row, you have to do  modular arithmetic yourself to achieve this..

Answer (score 1):

You can use OleDbDataAdapter to read all rows to fill a data set. And then select a row by index in the datatable of this dataset. An example to use OleDbDataAdapter is,

[DataAdapter.Fill(Dataset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532304/dataadapter-filldataset)