# Editing the Entire MS Access Database Row in VB.NET by just selecting the ID

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010

I have created an Application in VB.NET that is using MS Access as Data Source. I can successfully Add data in my Application. But here is the RUB! I want to edit my data after I selected it from my DataGridView. I can successfully Pass data from the DataGridView on another form by using this code

c_click = Me.C_supportDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index

Form2.Label8.Text = Me.C_supportDataGridView.Item(0, c_click).Value

Which solves my Problem A! But my problem B is how can I save this data in my MS Access database after I edit it in this form? I have an Idea in mind which is to select an ID or a certain cell which triggers to select it's corresponding row but I'm clueless on how to do this with MS Access! Any Advice?

Comment: Have a look at the `OleDbDataAdapter` + `DataSet` classes. You can bind Access tables to it having `Fill()` and `Update()` methods. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6532417/2882256) and [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sir. Let me check this 1st! :)